# Matplotlib df.dataframe x axis showing month and day

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The length of my x-axis is 168 (7 days * 24hrs). I want to show Jan 04th, Jan 05th ... Jan 10th) but can't seem to find how to do this.

```
plt.plot(t, php) 
plt.title('Electricity Load of heat pump at t')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=[25,7])
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2) 
tindex = np.arange(0,T)

dates = pd.date_range('20210104',periods=168, freq="H")

df = pd.DataFrame({'php1': php, 'dates': dates})

df.plot(kind='line',x='dates', y='php1',
        ax=axes, color ="red", linestyle='-', 
        linewidth=3, grid=True)
             
axes.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
axes.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=15) 
axes.get_legend().remove()
axes.set_ylabel('Power[kW]', fontsize=15)
axes.set_xlabel('Timeslot[Days] ', fontsize=15)
```

[image]

Comment: Did the already existing answers satisfy you? I don't think the code in the answer works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

mdate = mdates.DateFormatter('%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate)
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't seem like it's doing the trick..